# How to build text trimming cell for GWT DataGrid

Tags: java, gwt, datagrid, trim

I'm looking for examples for building a text-trimming cell for GWT DataGrid.
I want the cell to have fixed width and height, and if text is longer - ellipsis (...) will appear. The complete text will appear on editing / on tool tip.

In my current DataGrid, the text is automatically wrapped and the row height grows. I want to avoid that and to keep fixed row height.

Can someone help?
Thanks

Comment: You may want to implement your cell with your favorite logic; by overriding render() method of TextCell or AbstractCell you can do that. For example implementing any CSS (e.g. white-space: nowrap;) or trimming work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Create a CSS class and apply it to your DataGrid:

```
.myDataGrid td div {
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    -o-text-overflow: ellipsis;
    -ms-text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! 
Now the text gets trimmed, but i don't see the "..." for some reason. Any idea?
Moreover - if I want to see full content via tooltip - can this be done simply through CSS?

Comment: I edited my answer. Apparently for ellipsis to work, you need to apply this class to a div inside the cell of a DataGrid.

Comment: To answer your second question, you have two options. First option is to use css selector (i.e. .myDataGrid td div:hover) to set overflow to auto. Then your cell would expand to show the entire text when a user hovers over it. The second option is to show a tooltip, but that requires a custom cell or another solution (like showing a different popup panel when a user hovers over a cell). It's doable but a lot of work. I recommend waiting for GWT 2.5 because it would include some significant changes to DataGrid.

Comment: Thanks! Now I see the ellipsis as well.
I'll consider the options you mentioned about tooltip / cell expansion.